# RAM upgrades for a Dell Optiplex 3060 SFF

Tags: memory

I have a Dell optiplex 3060 SFF. With 4GB RAM. I'd like to upgrade it to 16GB. (**2x 8GB**)

Just want to double check this ram is compatible before I order it:

Crucial CT8G4DFS8266 8 GB (**x2**) DDR4, 2666 MT/s, PC4-21300 Single Rank x8 DIMM, 288-Pin

Current (stock) ram installed is skHynix (HMA851U6CJR6N)

Answer (score 0):

Your [existing RAM](https://www.skhynix.com/product/filedata/fileDownload.do?seq=9148) is single-rank and runs at 1.2 volts, as does the Crucial.  Their memory [meets Dell's specs](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/04/optiplex-3060-desktop/optiplex_3060_sff_setup_and_specs/memory) for your PC.  Crucial guarantees, if you buy from them, your PC will accept the [CT8G4DFS8266](https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Dell/optiplex-3060-sff) .  Looks safe to me.